# How to work with server response codes in java?

Tags: java

I am new to programming (especially in java) and I most likely lack knowledge with server work in java, my question is that I could send a request to the server and at the same time receive a response in the form of a response code, for example 404 (file not found), please someone tell me how to correctly implement this

the code we currently have

```
public static void Connection(int portNumber, String addr, String request) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(addr);
    String postData = request; // html request
    int response = 0;
    responses = response;
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length()));
    //<-------------------------------------Add a response code------------------------------------->//
    try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
        dos.writeBytes(postData);
    }
 
    try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                                    conn.getInputStream())))
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly. I've been scouring the internet and trying to find this in java books, but I haven't been able to find a proper answer

Comment: Pretty sure `con.getHeaderFields()` will give you a map that contains the status code. I wouldn't personally use these classes for making an HTTP request though. Java 10 added an HTTP client to the JDK, or there are 3rd party libraries which are better.

Comment: thank you, you solved my problem and even helped me with increasing my level of knowledge. I am very grateful

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send Http request and receive the data back you can just use 3d party Http clients. The most popular are [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/) with good tutorial - [Apache HttpClient Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-guide) and [OK Http client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/) with good tutorial - [A Guide to OkHttp](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp). However, If you want to learn how to use Java classes such as `URLConnection` so you can write your own code than I can offer you to look at source code of my own Http client that I wrote using those classes. This HttpClient can also be used as 3d party Http client (although it is a simplistic and not well-known as the 3d party clients I mentioned above), but also you can look at the source code that is not that big and (I hope) is well and clearly written. So it could be used as tutorial as well. This HttpClient comes as part of MgntUtils Open Source library written and maintained by me. Here is the source code of [HttpClient](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.java). Here is its [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html). If you want the source code of the whole library you can get it on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases), and just the library as Maven artifact is available from Maven Central [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils)